# ¿Como borrar la ultima coma de un concatenado de un sub query en sql? utilizando XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

la siguiente query devuelve dos campos (DATO1 Y DEPARTAMENTO ) QUE SON VARCHAR

```
SELECT DATO1 ,(SELECT   DD.NombreDepartamento +  ','  FROM CIALES AS CT INNER JOIN Departamento AS DD 
    ON CT.ID_DEPARTAMENTO = DD.IdDepartamento 
    ORDER BY CT.ID DESC 
    FOR XML PATH('') )
 AS DEPARTAMENTO FROM TABLA
```

El problema que tengo es que el campo DEPARTAMENTO .. como verán es una subquery , y que con el "for xml path" recorro los resultados, los concateno y les pongo una coma.. como separador, pero el problema es que también agrega la coma en el ultimo registro.

por ejemplo

devuelve = a,b,c,d,e,

yo quiero  = a,b,c,d,e

¿como lo hago ?

Comment: Hay alguna razon por la que pones tantos espacios alrededor de la coma? `'   ,   '`  y qué es `p` en `p.id`?

Comment: Hola,.. y gracias.. los espacios en blanco son para separar mas los nombres ya que el salto de linea no me funciona ... por eso hice el uso de coma...  y si el p.id no esta en esa definición..  ahora mismo lo arreglo.. gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editado:** *La respuesta no aplica tanto después de la última edición a la pregunta. Pero voy a dejar la respuesta por si ayuda a alguien en cuanto a ajustar el tercer parámetro de `stuff` dependiendo de la cadena usada para separar los elementos.*

---

Las demás respuestas, en cuanto a mover la *coma* al principio y usar `stuff`, son totalmente correctas. Solo deseo especificar que dependiendo de cuán larga es la cadena que usas para separar los elementos, debes ajustar el tercer parámetro de `stuff`.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, <strike>estás</strike> **estabas** usando `'   ,   '` (una coma rodeada por 3 espacios de cada lado), o sea 7 carácteres.

Siendo este el caso, necesitas que `stuff` remueva los 7 primeros carácteres, de modo que debes usar `7` como el tercer parámetro:

```
 select dato1,
        stuff((select '   ,   ' + dd.NombreDepartamento
           from ciales as ct
           join Departamento as dd
             on ct.id_departamento = dd.IdDepartamento
          where p.id = ct.id
          order by ct.id desc
          for xml path('')), 1, 7, '') as departamento
from tabla
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tenias mucha razón.. entendí el uso del stuff .. las otras respuestas son correctas . solo que no contaron con los espacios intencionales que están en la coma.  muchas gracias.. disculpa como podría hacer el salto de linea .. no me sale.

Answer (score 2):

Si ponemos la coma al principio en vez de al final es más fácil removerla usando la función [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Columna)
              FROM Tabla
              FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

`STUFF` puede insertar y remover caracteres de una cadena en una posición y longitud determinada

```
STUFF(...., -- cadena a modificar
      1, -- posición desde donde se modifica (empieza en 1, no en 0)
      1, -- cuantos caracteres se van a quitar
      '' -- cadena a insertar (vacío)
     )
```

Comment: gracias. pero en la coma había espacios. por lo tanto seria  .... for xml path('')), 1, 7, '') as departamento   igual muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Hazlo a la inversa y remueve la primera coma, valiéndote de la función [stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188043.aspx):

Así:

```
select dato1
       , stuff(
           (select ', ' + DD.NombreDepartamento
              from ciales as ct
                   inner join Departamento as dd on ct.id_departamento = dd.IdDepartamento
                   where p.id = ct.id
                   order by ct.id desc
                     for xml path('')
           )
           , 1, 2, '') as Departamento
  from tabla
```

### stuff

> La función STUFF inserta una cadena en otra. Elimina una longitud determinada de caracteres de la primera cadena a partir de la posición de inicio y, a continuación, inserta la segunda cadena en la primera, en la posición de inicio.

Comment: gracias. pero en la coma había espacios. por lo tanto seria  .... for xml path('')), 1, 7, '') as departamento   igual muchas gracias